# Is this statement true? Proving a theorem is equivalent to a problem in proving a Hamiltonian cycle of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, cryptography, hamiltonian-path

> Blum proved that any mathematical theorem can be converted into a graph such that the proof of that
> theorem is equivalent to proving a Hamiltonian cycle in the graph

from *Applied Cryptography* by Bruce Schneier

I'm struggling to understand what the statement means, and I was unable to find anything on it after a few quick google searches. Can someone point me in the right direction, to what this statement is even talking about?

Comment: This statement paraphrases Blum's paper "How to prove a Theorem So No One Else Can Claim It", Proc. of the ICM, Berkeley, California, USA, pages 1444-1451, 1986 which you can find here: https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/ICM/Proceedings/ICM1986.2/ICM1986.2.ocr.pdf